# How to check Device Orientation Change From Portrait To Landscape and Vice-Versa in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, orientation, screen-orientation

I have one split view controller and i am presenting a popover inside it. Now when the device orientation is changing from landscape to portrait i have to run a piece of code & if it is changing from portrait to landscape i have to run another piece of code. How to achieve this in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From iOS 8.0 You can detect the orientation change using below method.

**In objective-c**

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

**in swift**

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(_ size: CGSize,
    withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

from the size you can find out.

Comment: This method is not being called. I have a split view controller

Comment: **UISplitViewContoller** is also a subclass of **UIVIewController** .It should be called. One more important point check ur calling this method with super or not.The **viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:** seems to only work if the interface is actually going to change size, meaning we have rotated 90 degrees. If you have a mask on your layout that only allows landscape, when rotation 180 degrees, the interface size doesn't change, so this method doesn't seem to be called.

Answer (score 18):

Updated to Swift 4:
Add below code in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(orientationChanged), name:  Notification.Name("UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
```

Then, create one function like below

```
@objc func orientationChanged() {

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation)){

        print("landscape")
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation)){

        print("Portrait")
    }

}
```

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: UIDeviceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation