# How to determine device orientation when shouldAutorotate = NO and only portrait is allowed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rotation, orientation

I am working on a project where I want to replace the icons based on the orientation of the device without allowing the `viewController` to rotate. I have several `viewController` that are allowed to rotate and others, specified in my navigation controller that are not allowed to rotate.

This implementation works exactly how i want it to.

Code in my navigation controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    id currentViewController = self.topViewController;

    if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[ChimpTabBarController class]]) {
        ChimpTabBarController *tabbarController = (ChimpTabBarController*)currentViewController;

        if (tabbarController.selectedIndex == 0){
            return NO;
        }
    } else if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[RotationViewController class]] || [currentViewController isKindOfClass:[ChimpBlackoutVC class]] || [currentViewController isKindOfClass:[EditPictureVC class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}



-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    id currentViewController = self.topViewController;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;


    if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[ChimpTabBarController class]]) {
        ChimpTabBarController *tabbarController = (ChimpTabBarController*)currentViewController;

        if (tabbarController.selectedIndex == 0){
            return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
        }
    } else if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[RotationViewController class]] || [currentViewController isKindOfClass:[ChimpBlackoutVC class]] || [currentViewController isKindOfClass:[EditPictureVC class]]) {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Is there any way to find out which rotation my device wants to go to, but is not allowed? So that I can change the direction of an arrow, a word etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way myself, rather sooner than expected.

For your application you can use :

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

But when the rotation is *disabled* you can always ask the orientation of your device:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

Then in your viewcontroller you add an observer for when the device changed orientation:

-->[How to check Device Orientation Change From Portrait To Landscape and Vice-Versa in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591700/how-to-check-device-orientation-change-from-portrait-to-landscape-and-vice-versa)

Hope this will help people in the future.